# sj:datepicker in sjg:grid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, grid, datepicker

We are trying to create an sj:datepicker Calendar Control in an Editable sj:grid. The available edit types are only few (text, textarea, select).

We have seen examples in the jqGrid on how to bring a Datepicker within the grid rows, but couldn't find any similar option/implementation with the sjg:grid (Struts2-jQuery framework).

Has anyone implemented it ?

***Here is all the links & documentation we could find for jQGrid***:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config
[jqgrid Save Cell Edit When DatePicker Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471087/jqgrid-save-cell-edit-when-datepicker-is-closed)
[Jquery UI DatePicker In a JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346986/jquery-ui-datepicker-in-a-jqgrid)

[implement jqgrid cell edit datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629424/implement-jqgrid-cell-edit-datepicker)

[jqgrid Save Cell Edit When DatePicker Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471087/jqgrid-save-cell-edit-when-datepicker-is-closed)
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules

[jqgrid - use datepicker with dynamic colModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695043/jqgrid-use-datepicker-with-dynamic-colmodel)

[How do I add datepicker in the add row dialog in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152763/how-do-i-add-datepicker-in-the-add-row-dialog-in-jqgrid)

[jqgrid Save Cell Edit When DatePicker Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471087/jqgrid-save-cell-edit-when-datepicker-is-closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, i am not seeing a way to get the ***jquery.ui.datepicker.js*** file included automatically via the sj:head tag.

Step 1: Manually download & include the jquery.ui.datepicker.js file in your JSP  
Step 2: Add this jScript function to your JSP page

```
<script>
    datePick=function(element) { 
    $(element).datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            }
            );
    };
</script>
```

Step 3: Add the Grid Column for date. The editoptions is used to bring the calendar

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="dateOfBirth" index="dateOfBirth" title="Date of Birth"
    formatter="String" editable="true" editoptions="{size: 12, maxlength: 10, dataInit:datePick,attr:{title:'Select the date'} }"  ></sjg:gridColumn>
```

***Unanswered Question:*** 
         Is there a way to automatically include the jquery.ui.datepicker.js file using the struts2-jquery tags ? The `<sj:head jqueryui="true" ></sj:head>` is only including the following files.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/grid/struts/js/base/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/grid/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/grid/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/grid/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.3.3.min.js"></script>
```

eventhough the **jqueryui has been set to true**, i couldn't see the datepicker js file included automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instruction

```
<sj:head ... loadAtOnce="true"/>
```